# matplotlib tripcolor - removing edges

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `tripcolor` from `matplotlib.pyplot` to generate color plots of some data. The plot works great, but I'd like to turn off the edges which are drawn between data points:
[image]

subtle but pretty noticeable if you zoom in. I tried to get rid of them via:

```
plt.tripcolor(1e4*data_z, data_phi, data_I/1e3, shading='flat', edgecolors='none')
```

but the `edgecolors='none'` keyword arg seems to have no effect. I can, however, change the color from white to something else. Is there a way to get rid of them altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an example from the official documentation, and the property edgecolor seems working well.
This is the result with `edgecolors='w'`:

[image]

And this with `edgecolors='none'`:

[image]

I am using WinPython 3.3.5 (with Matplotlib 1.3.1) under Windows 7, maybe you have a different version?

Comment: I'm on OS X with python3, matplotlib 1.3.1. Interestingly, I just looked into that and it seems to depend on backend. With their example, the `'none'` edgecolor works fine in the native OS X backend, but when using `'agg'` and outputting to a eps file, then the phantom white edges appear.